# Ffmpeg - how to?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am working on an android app that allows a user to post videos files to an online server I suceeded in doing that but the problem come when uploading large videos. I am thinking of compressing the video before upload and I heard about ffmpeg but the thing is that I am just a beginner and I don't know where to start. Please what step do I need to follow to start using ffmpeg on android studio and how to use it to compress android videos

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with installing ffmpeg on your PC. Pull from your app some videos that you consider too large, and learn how you can use ffmpeg command line to convert this video to acceptable size and quality.

If you find this set of parameters, and believe that the conversion is not prohibitively slow, you can install ffmpeg on your Android device and prove that its results are acceptable, too.

Finally, you will learn to run ffmpeg programmatically from your app, and to package ffmpeg in your APK. But this step is easy, given that you resolved the first two.